# Как ограничить количество отправляемых заявок с формы на сайте?

Tags: php, javascript

На сайте есть форма, отправляющая заявки на почту.
Как можно ограничить количество заявок, отправляемых в единицу времени?
Например - 1 отправка в 5 минут.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript тут может быть только транспортом, полагаться на контроль только на клиентской стороне нельзя.

Нужно сохранять на сервере информацию о последней отправке сообщения данным пользователем. Для этого необходимо как-то идентифицировать пользователя: если аутентификация необязательна, то в качестве идентификатора можно использовать IP.

Общий алгоритм такой: При отправке сообщения сохраняем в базу отметку времени

```
INSERT INTO messages(user_id, msg_time) VALUES(:user_id, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

НО перед этим пробуем узнать когда была последняя отправка

```
SELECT MAX(msg_time) FROM messages WHERE user_id = :user_id
```

И если это было менее чем N минут назад, отменяем операцию. Код на PHP будет зависит от выбранного фреймворка, но суть надеюсь уже понятна.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще правильно в этом случае ограничивать запросы на сервере - по id сессии юзера или куке.

Но если на клиенте просто надо запретить запуск чего-либо слишком часто, к вашим услугам условный оператор `if`:

```
var disableRequest, requestDelay = 3000, timeoutInstance; 

function delayedAjaxRequest() {
  if(disableRequest) return;
  doMyRequest();
  disableRequest = true;
  timeoutInstance = setTimeout(function () {disableRequest = false;}, requestDelay);
}
```

Если вы хотите сохранять запрет между перезагрузками страницы данного пользователя - храните оставшееся время таймаута в куках или localStorage.

Если статически определённая процедура должна вызываться не чаще чем в некий промежуток времени, можно использовать такую обёртку для неё:

```
function moderate(fn, dt) {
 if(!dt) dt = 100;
 if(fn.moderateTimer) {
   clearTimeout(fn.moderateTimer);
 }
 fn.moderateTimer = setTimeout(fn, dt);
}
```

следующим образом:

```
sendMyAjax = function() {
  $http.get('http://...', {q : 'test'})
}

moderate(sendMyAjax, 3000);
moderate(sendMyAjax, 3000);
```

Разумеется, sendMyAjax может быть фабрикой-генератором функций или можно усовершенствовать `moderate` посредством `apply` или `call` для передачи параметров функции, но для большинства кейсов хватает минималистичной реализации. Полезно добавить callback для обработки преждевременного запуска:

```
function moderate(fn, dt, cb) {
 if(!dt) dt = 100;
 if(fn.moderateTimer) {
   clearTimeout(fn.moderateTimer);
   cb();
 }
 fn.moderateTimer = setTimeout(fn, dt);
}

moderate(sendMyAjax, 3000, function () { alert('Не чаще чем в 3 сек'); });
```

Comment: минусатор: не осилил, *многобукоф*?

Answer (score 0):

В такой постановке вопроса - никак.
Ну, то есть, можно конечно писать в файл время отправки, и не отправлять форму, если не прошло еще 5 минут.
Но тогда проще будет вообще форму отключить - если ее так сильно спамят, то спамеры будут успевать раньше реального юзера, который просто плюнет и уйдет.

Если хочется ограничить спам, то так и надо писать. Для борьбы со спамом существует капча.

Comment: Нет, задача не в защите от спама. Просто ограничение на одну отправку для одного человека. А если в файл писать, то форма будет блокироваться для всех? Возможно ли ограничить средствами JavaScript? Форма отправляется аяксом.

Answer (score 0):

Под человеком вы понимаете авторизованного пользователя или не авторизованного?
Если авторизованного, то все просто - записываете время обработки формы и id пользователя (можно прямо с данными из формы записывать), а дальше при обработке ajax-а проверяете время последней записи данных от текущего пользователя.
Если для не авторизованного, то необходимо записывать кроме времени еще и id сессии и также проверять.

Answer (score 0):

Например, после отправки заявки можно добавить куку со временем истечения now() + 5*60 sec и при следующей отправке проверять, истекло ли время жизни куки. Если нет, то по ситуации можно предупреждать пользователя что до следующей отправки осталось n минут
Либо в приложении держать map где kay - юзер, value - время последней отправки формы

Answer (score 0):

Создаете таблицу formRequestes с полями для идентицикации пользователя, к примеру IP и временем удачного отправки формы.

Дальше, перед отправкой формы, проверяете эту таблицу на наличие пользователя с таким же IP и сравниваете текущее время и время последнего запроса. Ну и даете возможность отправки или же выводите соответствующее предупреждение.